# Conda update is too much time on Centos

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Conda is taking too much time on CentOS. I m running the command conda --debug update conda. Here is the log not sure why it's taking too much time.

```
DEBUG:conda.fetch:channel_urls=OrderedDict([('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/', ('defaults', 1)), ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/', ('defaults', 1)), ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/', ('defaults', 1)), ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/', ('defaults', 1))])
Fetching package metadata ...INFO:stdoutlog:Fetching package metadata ...
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry:Converted retries value: 3 -> Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.continuum.io
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry:Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f625c420d10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): repo.continuum.io
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry:Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f625c420e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (3): repo.continuum.io
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry:Incremented Retry for (url='/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f625dc08050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (4): repo.continuum.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this problem resolve itself for you?  The problem, as the debug output shows, is that you were unable to access https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 -- this is only a 300KB file.  But the issue was not download time, it was that your client simply couldn't get a response from that URL.  I work at Continuum and I am not aware of any service disruption that would have meant repo.continuum.io was not available any time in the past 24 hours, however I am not part of the ops team.  I would put that URL into your web browser or phone and see if it resolves OK for you.  If it does then the problem is more likely on the CentOS server where you are executing the `conda update` command.  You can always try a `wget` or `curl` command to see if those resolve the URL successfully.  Let us know if those suggestions help you get it working or at least identify the source of the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of this, the issue is not the download taking too much time, but you are unable to get a response from the URL.  The most likely cause is because you have a firewall configured incorrectly, as Ian recommended see if you can resolve the URL through a different measure, potentially even through a different machine/VM.